# What are the first 3 non-null terms of the following Maclaurin series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

What are the first 3 non-null terms of the following Maclaurin series?

$$f(x) = (4+x^2)^\frac52$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x) = 32(1+x^2/4)^{5/2}$. Now use the generalized binomial theorem, 
$$(1+x)^s = 1 + sx + \frac{s(s-1)}{2}x^2 +\ldots.$$